# Trying to run php-fpm 5.6 alongside php7.2 for different Apache virtual hosts on EC2 amazon linux , what am I missing?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4, amazon-linux

I'm working on amazon linux on an EC2 instance.
I installed php72 using yum, apache worked fine.
I have installed php5.6 at `/opt/php5.6` configured it as fpm and done the make install whcih all went fine, I can start and stop it fine but I'm unclear about what are the other steps I need to take.

I've added a config file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php5.6-fpm.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler php56-fcgi .php
Action php56-fcgi /php56-fcgi
Alias /php56-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php56-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
Action php70-fcgi /php70-fcgi
Alias /php70-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
</IfModule>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

but I'm unclear as to what these (`/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php70-fcgi`) should be, they don't exist on my filesystem.
I''ve been hacking around using different webpages so I'm not quite clear about the elements required to trigger the installed php5.6 from a virtual host or of how to customise the above config to my setup.

I do know I need to add in declarations to the virtual host config.  I found this online but I'm not clear how to translate this into my setup.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
        Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
        Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-example.com
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-example.com -socket /var/run/php5-fpm-example.com.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

Any pointers would be very gratefully received.